# How to change separator line color for single table section?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to change the separator line color for single table section? I have several sections, but I want to change it only for one of them. In interface builder I can change the color only for all table section separator lines.

```
switch(indexPath.section){
   case 0:
      tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.redColor()
      break
   case 1:
       and so on...
}
```

This one doesn't work for me.

Comment: In which UITableview delegate  method you have written this code?

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}

Comment: also tried in

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell:   UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`separatorColor` is a property of a `UITableView`. You can't specify a section and you're therefore not specifying a section. So of course the property applies to the whole table view.

The built-in view can't automatically vary colours by section. You'll have to incorporate the separator into your table view cells, or insert separator cells between your existing cells. It's a pain but your options are limited.

Comment: So, as I realized I can't change section border color?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The built-in class doesn't support per-section separator colours. It doesn't matter when you set the property, as the semantics suggest you're setting for the whole table.

Answer (score 3):

You are able to set the separatorInset which is cell specific, so providing you take care of any changes in orientation (and reload the relevant cells that may require the inset to be adjusted to the new width), you can use something like:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: tableView.frame.size.width, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

This will allow you to effectively remove the inset on a cell by cell basis.